# ssh login failed with public key

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, sshd

### I use publickey to do ssh login and failed. Here is my sshd config, sshd logs.

- sshd config:

```
Port 1046
Protocol 2
PermitRootLogin no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
UsePAM yes
UseDNS no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
LogLevel VERBOSE
PermitRootLogin yes
```

- sshd logs:

```
Connection from 10.17.149.17 port 62226 on 10.246.250.39 port 1046
Accepted key RSA SHA256:b6Yc1ppLdo25TtZ++V8/m69yD+yN4R7f9fhBYieu7Xo found at /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:4
Postponed publickey for root from 10.17.149.17 port 62226 ssh2 [preauth]
Accepted key RSA SHA256:b6Yc1ppLdo25TtZ++V8/m69yD+yN4R7f9fhBYieu7Xo found at /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:4
ROOT LOGIN REFUSED FROM 10.17.149.17 port 62226
Failed publickey for root from 10.17.149.17 port 62226 ssh2: RSA SHA256:b6Yc1ppLdo25TtZ++V8/m69yD+yN4R7f9fhBYieu7Xo
ROOT LOGIN REFUSED FROM 10.17.149.17 port 62226 [preauth]
Failed publickey for root from 10.17.149.17 port 62226 ssh2: RSA SHA256:wh/ZJ9J+jAYatcc33JV0CN8zwyMKSuEshaQ7+8h6I0g
Failed publickey for root from 10.17.149.17 port 62226 ssh2: RSA SHA256:bt40UTWH5hHROPkP7G+84S5pq1YUqTjtRHoB7WZAf8A
Failed publickey for root from 10.17.149.17 port 62226 ssh2: RSA SHA256:pcexRDoFoAPQ5ja1LuMcgacbudXMFcrJ1bdBkuYENzg
Connection closed by authenticating user root 10.17.149.17 port 62226 [preauth]
```

Comment: Set PermitRootLogin to yes and then reload the sshd daemon.
what OS is this.

Comment: Remove the third line of your config file. (the one that says PermitRootLogin no)

Comment: ok, I add `PermitRootLogin yes` to the last line, didn't notice the third line.